# Define webroot outside folder path

Tags: php

I have folder structure like this:

```
  public_html
     /index.php   
  outside
     /other.php
```

I want in `public_html/index.php` include file, which is place in `outside` folder. So, I want define outside folder path in `public_html/index.php` file. I make this so:

**index.php**

```
 $doc_root_upper = preg_replace("#/[^/]+$#", "", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
 $outside_folder = $doc_root_upper."/outside";
 include outside_folder.'/other.php';
```

This works, but there is better practice for define webroot outside folder path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal preference is to start my `init.php` file (included by php.ini's `auto_prepend_file` directive) with `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`.

This means that all of my includes and other file functions are done from the document root.

In your case, this means you can then do `include ../outside/other.php` reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Use a relative path like this:

```
Include("../outside/other.php");
```

../ means up one directory.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a `chdir()` to get the explicit paths and then add them to the include path. I tend to have a file called `init.php` that contains the following:

```
$path = get_include_path(); // get the current path
$oldcwd = getcwd(); // get the current path

// change to outside of the document root
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/.."); 
$newcwd = getcwd(); // get the new working directory

// build the new path. Using hte _SEPARATOR constants ensures 
// that it works on all platforms.
$newpath = $path . PATH_SEPARATOR . $newcwd . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "outside"; 

// Set the new path
set_include_path($newpath);

chdir($oldcwd); // change back to the original working directory
```